# How do i add a Logo to my bootstrap nav bar aligned vertically and pulled to the left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys i have been trying to add my company logo to the bootstrap nav bar, and my logo is saved in Images/Logo.jpg in the same Directory as that of my index.html, But i just cant seem to add a logo to my nav bar, all i can see is my text for logo and no image. Please help me here is my code. Thanks

HTML

```
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" class="pull-left" href="#myPage">
  <img src="Images/Logo.jpg">The Concetto</span>
</a>


    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">CAREER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
  .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      z-index: 9999;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
      color: #f4511e !important;
      background-color: #fff !important;

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
  }
```

Comment: have you tried using `/Images/Logo.jpg`?

Comment: yes tried! No Luck

Comment: Also verify the file extension just to be sure ( .jpg or .jpeg)

Comment: Check this fiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_Hero/frqzj4wc/2/)

Comment: If it doesn't work for you like the snippet @MacHero provided the problem is not in the syntax, but in the location of the file. I know you said you already checked the saving location, but something is off there, if the code itself is correct.